# How can I force Windows 7 to update the user profile path?

Tags: windows-7

I renamed a user profile to a new name. This worked but when I look into the folder path, the old name is being used. Why? And how can I make the folder pathname the same as the new name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This might work for you:](http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-move-user-data-folder-to-non-system-partition-in-windows-7vista/)

It let's you relocate your user profile. So you simply relocate it to a folder that has the name you want it to have and it will replace the old name.

> Microsoft supplies a tool ***mklink***
>   which can create a symbolic link under
>   Windows 7 just as the command ln under
>   unix/linux. Below is an example about
>   how to put user data on in a
>   non-system folder using mklink in
>   Windows 7.
>
> - Enable administrator account and set a password for it. You can refer How
>     to enable or disable administrator
>     account in windows 7
> - Logoff and login with administrator account
> - Relocate your user data to other non-system partion, for example from
>     C:\users\J  to D:\users\J
> - Use mklink to create a symbolic link from C:\users\J to D:\users\J
>
>   mklink /D C:\Users\J  D:\users\J
> - Re-login use your own account,you will find nothing changed, but in fact
>     your physical user data is on drive D.
> - Done. The next time you re-install your OS, just use the same user name,
>     remove  C:\users\J then run the
>     command of step 3 again then your user
>     data is back.

Comment: Accepted answer and +1 and +1 credit to Om Nom Nom as well for GUI. I'm hoping I can use this answer for the following: started with admin user/profile BOB with folder C:\Users\BOB. Had a strange profile won't load error when trying to login one day. So had to create new admin profile/user ROB with folder C:\Users\ROB and copy BOB's data over. Renamed ROB in Windows user management to BOB but folder path remained same i.e. C:\Users\ROB. So I'm hoping I can use your answer to get it back to C:\Users\BOB.

Comment: Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 4):

Just fyi, there is a GUI to make the creation of symbolic links easier - [symlinker](http://code.google.com/p/symlinker/)

[image]

> With this utility you can use the
>   symlink application Microsoft Windows
>   has well hidden inside the cmd.exe
>   app.
>
> The goal is just make it easier to
>   create symbolic links, hard links, or
>   directory junctions, using a pretty
>   simple interface, so no more bogus
>   command line to do it...
>
> This application needs .Net Framework
>   3.5 to run (SP1 recommended)

Comment: +1 That's my answer, only a lot easier!

Comment: True, I wanted to post this as a comment to your post, but I didn't have the required reputation for that.

Answer (score 0):

try just CMD> `gpupdate /force` to update the user rights